# get_form in ModelAdmin causing TypeError

Tags: django, python-3.x

This question refers to the issue I was having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897504/how-to-pass-kwargs-from-modeladmin-to-modelform) which has not been solved. I have created a new simplified version of the `MemoForm` called `AdminMemoForm` to help me isolate the issue. After creating the new version of the form I have come to find that the `get_form` method is what is causing the `TypeError: MemoForm object not callable.` Here is a snippet of the new code that is throwing the error:

**Forms.py**:

```
class AdminMemoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Memo creation form, related to:

    :model: 'memos.Memo',
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Memo
        fields = (
            'title',
            'content',
            'important',
            'word_file',
            'receiver',
            'read',
            'unread',
        )
```

**Admin.py**:

```
class CustomMemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminMemoForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    #     if not request.user.is_superuser:
    #         self.fields = (
    #             'title',
    #             'content',
    #             'important',
    #             'receiver',
    #             'read',
    #             'unread',
    #             'word_file',
    #         )
    #     self.filter_horizontal = ('casino',)
        return form()
```

The full error:

```
TypeError at /admin/memos/memo/add/
'MemoForm' object is not callable
```

Another question is why is this error showing the old form `MemoForm` and not the new `AdminMemoForm`? It is registered: `admin.site.register(Memo, CustomMemoAdmin)`

This is probably simple but I don't get why this error is arising. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the return from your `get_form()` function be:
`return form` without the quotes, as you've created it with the call to `super().get_form()`?

Comment: I am currently handling a different portion of the project but as soon as I finish it I am going to look over this. I don't know what I was thinking here but I believe you are right. Thank you for taking the time to point out my dumb mistake.

Comment: If I had £1 for every time I did something like this... :) Did this solve your issue?

Comment: I believe so XD